# A question on divisible groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be a prime and $H=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb Z(p^{n})$ ($\mathbb Z(p^{n})$ is the finite cyclic group of order $p^{n}$). Is $H/t(H)$ divisible ($t(H)$ denotes the maximal torsion subgroup of $H$)?

Comment: Do u have the book of Susuki I?

Comment: @ Babak S No, i do not have.

Comment: This is a nice fact proved in the book *Group Theory I* by M.Susuki page 148 (b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does $(1,1,1,\cdots)$ have a $p$th root modulo torsion?

If so, we have $(1,1,1,\cdots)+(a_1p^{e_1},a_2p^{e_2},a_3p^{e_3},\cdots)=p(b_1,b_2,b_3,\cdots)$ for various choices of integers $a_i,e_i,b_i$ (chosen so $a_i$ are all prime to $p$). The torsion condition implies $p\mid p^{e_{\large i}}$ eventually, in which case $1+a_ip^{e_i}=pb_i$ immediately yields a contradiction upon reducing mod $p$.

However it is clearly $q$-divisible for every prime $q\ne p$. In particular it is a ${\bf Z}_{(p)}$-module, where ${\bf Z}_{(p)}$ denotes the [localization](http://planetmath.org/localization) of $\bf Z$ at $(p)$. This is perhaps easiest seen by expanding the interpretation of the original group to be a product ring, and considering the maps ${\bf Z}_{(p)}\to {\bf Z}_{(p)}/p^n{\bf Z}_{(p)}\cong {\bf Z}/p^n{\bf Z}$.